# Installed latest node-sass but project keeps attempting to install node-sass 4.9.0

Tags: node.js, npm, ionic3, npm-install, node-sass

I am attempting to run an ionic theme in Windows 10 but I have trouble when I run "npm install" returning the error

```
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
```

I checked for several solutions online. I installed windows build tools, npm-gyp and eventually managed to install the latest node sass (node-sass@4.14.0) globally and in my project folder but when I attempt to run "npm install" it still attempts to install node-sass@4.9.0 despite the latest version of node-sass being already installed.

I have tried to check for any reference of node-sass@4.9.0 in the package.json or anywhere else in the project folder but cant find any. I am using node v14.5.0, npm v6.14.6.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the package-lock.json, you should be able to search to see what dependency is depending on the old version of node-sass